# Is std::chrono::time_point thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` variable that I am modifying across threads, is this variable thread safe?  If not, I intend to make it atomic.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If the documentation doesn't mention thread safety, assume it's not safe. Thread safety costs a lot and C++ has a policy of not forcing a program to pay for anything it's not using. The vast majority of cases require no thread safety, so forcing it on them violates the only pay for what you use policy. Worse, most of the time you want to make a whole transaction thread safe, to protecting one small corner thread safe is usually wasted effort. Java found that out the hard way with `Vector`.

Comment: Do you mean you may be modifying it in two threads at the same time? Or do you mean one thread might be modifying it while another thread is accessing it and you need to make sure the accessing thread gets either value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` variable that I am modifying across threads, is this variable thread safe?

No. `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` is not guaranteed to be thread safe.